# Custom Button to Generate an email using email template

Tags: javascript, button

We have a custom button on our Opportunity, this allows for PDF to be generated providing a snapshot of the opportunity in that moment. I also need to send a copy to a group email and also the assorted members in the internal project team captured in the opportunity through an email template.

I have yet to learn javascript (am also a full time IT student, ironically javascript is next semester) so I am flailing around in the dark a bit. Below is what we currently have which was within my capability.

Label: Create Customer Sales Order

**`OnClick JavaScript`**

//AWESOME BUTTON

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/36.0/connection.js")} 
{ 
 console.log("/apex/AttachPDFToOpp?Id={!Opportunity.Id}"); 
 window.open("/apex/AttachPDFToOpp?Id={!Opportunity.Id}", "_parent"); 
}
```

group email is called **`internalorders@compacsort.com`** and I have created the email template '**CSO Email**' and we have the project team fields

Market Sales Engineer, Financial Project Manager, Financial Office Engineer, 
Production Project Manager, Design House Sales Engineer, Regional Project Manager

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have something that it is easy to implement and I think that can really help you in your requirement. A couple of days ago someone in this forum was asking something similar so here it is what I proposed him to do:

There is a way to send emails from a button with any template. I don't know if this is the best option or exactly what you need but I can send emails by adding a button in the object I need to send the email from just by using this url:

> /_ui/core/email/author/EmailAuthor?rtype=003&p3_lkid={!Case.Id}&retURL=%2F{!Case.Id}&p5={!$User.Email}&p24="AdditionalEmailAddresGoesHere&template_id=00X58000000sJE3

Got to Set up
Build
Your SObject -> Task Buttons, Links and Actions
Click in New Button or Link
Insert label name, select Detail Page Button
Behavior = Display in a new window
Content Source = URL
Insert this:

> /_ui/core/email/author/EmailAuthor?rtype=003&p3_lkid={!Case.Id}&retURL=%2F{!Case.Id}&p5={!$User.Email}&p24="AdditionalEmailAddresGoesHere&template_id=00X58000000sJE3

The last part of this link needs to point out to the email template you want to use for your email, so change the **"template_id=00X58000000sJE3"** to your template id. If you want to use this link in another button for another object you can do that by changing the parts in which you see **"Case"** for the object you want to use. I have tested this on the case and opportunity objects and works fine.

Let me know if it is also working for you.

Don't forget to add you new button to your custom button section in the pages you need to.

Good luck and let us know the outcome.

Comment: OP looking for a custom button that renders a PDF `and` attaches result to an outbound email

Comment: Thank you. Sorry it was a long weekend in NZ so just back in the office. I will review and update.